# Celebrate a victory with Open Graph on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-opengraph

After almost 2 days of reading through the Facebook docs, I still can't figure out why oh why my code for simply publishing a game victory does not work. If I use Facebook Sample's object, it does work (uncommented), but once I use the object, the app crashes and opens the browser (in simulator) and returns to the game again. The code is as follows:

```
NSDictionary *properties = @{
                                 @"og:type": @"games.victory",
                                 @"og:title": @"A Game Victory",
                                 @"og:description": @"Awsum description",
                                 };
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject *object = [FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject objectWithProperties:properties];

    // Create an action
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction *action = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction alloc] init];
    action.actionType = @"games.celebrate";
    [action setString:@"http://samples.ogp.me/500426766634310" forKey:@"victory"];
 //   [action setObject:object forKey:@"victory"];

    // Create the content
    FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent *content = [[FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent alloc] init];
    content.action = action;
    content.previewPropertyName = @"victory";




    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                                 withContent:content
                                    delegate:nil];
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this, I'm quite done with the FB documentation. Also, how could I know whether the story has been posted successfully in my app? Is there some delegate callback function or anything like that?

Comment: Yes, there's a delegate callback function. In your sample code you're setting the delegate to nil. If in the class you're calling the code, you implement FBSDKSharingDelegate methods, you will know when the post was successfull, when it failed and why it failed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKShareDialog/#mode, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKSharingDelegate/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#onsuccess

Comment: And I think you should try running your app in a real device too!